# How to parse a "QFX" export file from Quicken (2020) on a Mac

Tags: quicken

Quicken on a Mac has two ways to export all the data: to a QIF file and a QXF file.  When I export it to a QIF file, I get warnings and the file is 141K.  When I export it to a QXF file, I do not get warnings and the file is 3M.  So I'm very curious in what the QXF file contains.

QFX is suppose to be OFX which is an xml format.  But when I look at the QFX output file that Quicken produces, it is a binary file.  `file` simply says "data".  `uncompress` and `ungzip` both say its not recognizable.

`od -cx file.qxf | head` gives

```
0000000  274   3   7 315 217 337 360 253   ~   B 240 313   / 323   ]   9
             33bc    cd37    df8f    abf0    427e    cba0    d32f    395d
0000020  264 317 352 236   ? 205   ֯  **   T 027   0 224 255   [   h 025
             cfb4    9eea    853f    afd6    1754    9430    5bad    c468
0000040  025 317 303   r 350 240   ӥ  **   P 250   f 255 027 244 261 023
             cf15    72c3    a0e8    a5d3    a850    ad66    a417    13b1
0000060    u   < 255 352 274   ^   6   i 340 024 020 277   @ 214  \t 016
             3c75    eaad    5ebc    6936    14e0    bf10    8c40    e809
0000100  016 376 375 355 300 221 201 263 261 031 244 224 201 210 234   W
             fe0e    edfd    91c0    b381    19b1    94a4    8881    579c
```

`od -x file.qxf | head` gives:

```
0000000      33bc    cd37    df8f    abf0    427e    cba0    d32f    395d
0000020      cfb4    9eea    853f    afd6    1754    9430    5bad    c468
0000040      cf15    72c3    a0e8    a5d3    a850    ad66    a417    13b1
0000060      3c75    eaad    5ebc    6936    14e0    bf10    8c40    e809
0000100      fe0e    edfd    91c0    b381    19b1    94a4    8881    579c
0000120      e49a    3f58    01d2    bc7f    50fb    3d2a    c742    525e
0000140      6680    8d21    6938    42cf    5148    54a4    04c5    def6
0000160      e32f    3903    16ff    0e1b    4e94    392d    054f    6c81
0000200      6775    4e2d    9a5f    4520    56fa    dc09    dccd    1984
0000220      da66    065b    303e    ccf0    03a6    7354    ef1f    a217
```

Any ideas on how to parse / decode this?

Comment: There are three file types: QIF, QFX and QXF.  QFX is derived from OFX.  Your examples above are of QXF which is a Quicken proprietary format.